# SciPy QZ generalized eigenvectors

Tags: python, scipy, eigenvalue

I am using SciPy's `linalg.qz` function to generate eigenvalues for an ill-conditioned generalised eigenvalue problem using two input matrices A, B.

The [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qz.html) for the function gives 4 quantities to unpack:

```
AA, BB, Q, Z = linalg.qz(A,B)
```

AA and BB represent the generalised Schur form of A and B respectively.

Q and Z represent the left and right Schur vectors respectively.

When looking at the [Matlab](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qz.html) implementation of this function there are two extra returns, V and W whose columns are generalised eigenvectors:

```
[AA,BB,Q,Z,V,W] = qz(A,B)
```

As these two returns are not possible directly from the `linalg.qz` function, what would be the most efficient means to extract the generalised eigenvectors from the left and right Schur vectors?

Answer (score 0):

The answer's there in the original paper of the qz algorithm. You want to look at step 5 on page  251 of https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0710024?journalCode=sjnaam.
Fortran code is also available in the older version of this paper.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and eventually turned to the low-level LAPACK functions offered by scipy.

In matlab, the quantities can be found as

```matlab
[AA,BB,Q,Z,V,W] = qz(A,B)
```

In python, the same results can be computed as

```py
from scipy.linalg import qz
from scipy.linalg.lapack import zggev

# matlab uses complex output by default
# python uses real
AA, BB, Q, Z = qz(A, B, 'complex')
_, _, V, W, _, _ = zggev(A, B)
```

Different versions of the LAPACK ggev functions depend on the datatypes (real vs complex and single vs double). Documentation [here](http://www.icl.utk.edu/%7Emgates3/docs/lapack.html) among many other places.